# Как вызвать flask-view функцию из JQuery диалога?

Tags: jquery, python, flask

Есть код приведенный ниже, который вызывает всплывающее окно:

```
<a class="popup-link-1" href="">Click me</a>

<div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-1">
 ... some content here
</div>
```

JQuery диалог взял отсюда: http://sitear.ru/material/jquery-popup-okno

Как вызвать view-функцию фласка, чтобы рендерить разные  шаблоны внутри этого окна?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите документацию `Flask` там все достаточно подробно, вот пример `login.html` из инета:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
  {% if error %}<p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}{% endif %}
  <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method=post>
    <dl>
      <dt>Username:
      <dd><input type=text name=username>
      <dt>Password:
      <dd><input type=password name=password>
      <dd><input type=submit value=Login>
    </dl>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

И функция `Flask`:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] == 'user' and request.form['password'] == 'pass':
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('you_template'))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid username or password'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Если средствами `JS` смотрите доки `http` запросов, например [тут](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)